# Column not found Magento2

Tags: magento2, database, model, massaction

I am using magento 2.1 C.E. I have initialized my own model with a custom table. I am trying to implement mass actions and clicking on one of the massactions, I get this error:

`Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause'`

Below is my massaction controller code:
`Index/MassAccept.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class MassAccept extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    protected $resultPageFactory = false;
    protected $_moduleFactory;
    protected $filter;

    public function __construct(
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $moduleFactory,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Context $context
        ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->_moduleFactory = $moduleFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        // $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParams('id');
        // Create/load module model
        $model = $this->_moduleFactory->create();
        // Get collection of the loaded model using filter to get the data
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($model);

        foreach($collection as $item) {
            echo $item->getId();
        }
        die();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: pass your primary key in id of param. $this->getRequest()->getParams('primary_key');

Comment: I am sending this from grid, but I am not able to fetch them properly. And yes, the id is getiing sent here. I am using my custom model as you can see in the code

Answer (score 1):

your modele have to impliment data service and it has getId() with you id key situated in database table and then only you can get collection from `$item->getId()`

else you need to retrive data using proper id name like 'getBannerId()'